# AspNetCore SignalR 1.0.0-rc1-final NTLM/Negotiate authentication with C# managed client

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-signalr

In the ASP.NET version it's extremely simple:

hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

How can I accomplish this in the new AspNetCore C# managed client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this within the options of "WithUrl"

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("/chatHub", o => { o.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; })
            .Build();
```

[Docs ASP.NET Core Signalr Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-additional-options)